# Where to store short strings (with my key) on the internet?

Tags: curl, irc, dynamic-dns

Is there simple service to store strings under my key that can be used by bots?

Requirements:

1. Simple command line access, automatic posting allowed
2. No need to keep some session with the service alive
3. I choose the key (so pastebins fail)
4. No requirement for registration/authentication (for simplicity)
5. The string should be kept for about a month.

I want something like:

```
Store:
$ echo some_data_0x1299C0FF | store_my_string testtest2011

Retrieve:
$ retrive_my_string testtest2011
some_data_0x1299C0FF
```

Do you have ideas what should I use for it? I can only think of using IRC somehow (channel topics, `/whowas`, ...), but this is too complex for this simple task.

No security is needed: anyone can update my string. The task looks very simple, so I expect the solution to be similarly simple. Expecting something like single simple `curl` call.

Comment: That had better not be [the kind of bots I'm thinking about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_computer).

Comment: @grawity, Bot here means the program will run on shedule (or in response to events) and change the string for that key. In my use case the even is change of Teredo IP and the action is updating content of some known key with the new IPv6 address. (workarounding dyndns).

Comment: @Vi: Aha. And what problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @grawity, Making poor man's dyndns where you can add hosts easily (without launching a browser and pre-registering anything or using specialized "dyndns updaters" as clients), Security is not an issue, it's handled by SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DNS `TXT` records to store strings in such a manner. I'm not sure how easily they would be to set, but that would depend upon how your DNS server is set up.

Comment: 1. I mean public services, not "my" servers.
2. Settings DNS records without any credentials?

Basically I want to use it as alternative to dynamic DNS as dyndns are full with registrations, speciallized clients and "pay to have more that 2 hosts" things.

Comment: @Vi: There are public DNS hosts (such as http://freedns.afraid.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You usually can't get away from the 3rd requirement unless you host your own service – due to possible problems caused by collisions. There is an ugly workaround: hide the pastebin behind a link shortener – some of them, such as http://tinyurl.com/, allow choosing your own prefix.

Most pastebins allow retrieval of the "raw" paste, and submitting can be done with a simple HTTP request. The simplest is *sprunge*:

```
$ echo "This is a test" | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us
 http://sprunge.us/fiea

$ curl http://sprunge.us/fiea
This is a test
```

Comment: When I do second invocation I don't know the exact key. The key should be known by both peers beforehand. Also it will be good it I can update the string by that key.

Comment: Collisions? I also want to override the value for a key. In short, I want thing like dynamic DNS, but without the hassle with registration.

Comment: @Vi: You could use something like http://pastie.org/ in that case - create a paste, distribute the key, edit the paste.

Comment: pastice.org> "You appear to be a bot, I can't accept your paste. JS is now required to paste." => too unfriendly.